# Accessing an data in a JSON object in Next JS

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I have an object that contains another object. Accessing the properties of the inner object isn't working.

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from "../../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const News = (data:any) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="section section-main-page pt-0">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="section section-panel">
                        <div className="section-panel-content">
                            <h1>{data.state.name}/{data.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default News;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context:any) =>{
    let data = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + '/' + context.query.state +'/news/' + 'test-news-article')
        .then( r => r.json() )
    console.log(data.state.name);
    return {props: {data}}
}
```

when I console data, it works. But as per the code above, nothing gets printed where the title should be. Also when trying to access `data.state.name`. I get an error.

Here is my data

```
{
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test News Article',
    summary: 'This is the summary',
    state: { id: '9', name: 'National'}
}
```

Comment: what console.log is showing ?

Answer (score 0):

you are returning `{props: {data}}`
so it has to be `props.data.state.name`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `const News = (data:any)` to `const News = ({data}:any)` fixed it.